# Video on blogger goes outside the page (MOBILE VERSION)

Tags: html, css, mobile, youtube, blogger

When I publish a page on Blogger with a video, the mobile version of the page does not fit the video. Please see attached screen shot below. An example of a blog page where this happens:
http://www.socialguidez.com/2016/11/3-badass-viral-marketing-techniques-for.html?m=1

[image: Video on blogger goes outside the page (SCREEN SHOT)]

Comment: Check out this article: https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Comment: Thank you guys. Appriciate the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Template** > **Edit HTML**. then in the `<head>` search for this tag `]]></b:skin>` and put this code before it.

```
.post-body iframe {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest

```
iframe {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```